# react native generator function not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, redux-saga

I tried to use generator functions and want to check a Token. If a Token exists then I want it display with console.log. But nothing happens why? I also get no errors.

getToken.js

```
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';

const getSecureStore = async () => {
  // Check if key already exists 
  const keyExists = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('uuid');

  return keyExists;
};

function* storeToken() {
  while(true) {
    const keyExists = yield call(getSecureStore());
    console.log(keyExists);
  }
}

export default storeToken;
```

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import AppStack from './src/navigation/stack';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
import getSecureKey from './src/utilities/getSecureKey';

const App = () => {
  const [firstContent, setFirstContent] = useState(false);

  const loadContent = async () => {

    await getSecureKey();
  };

  if(firstContent) {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <AppStack />
      </NavigationContainer>
    )
  } else {
    return (<AppLoading startAsync={loadContent} onFinish={() => setFirstContent(true)} onError={e => console.error(e)} />)
  }
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Where are you using your `storeToken`?

Comment: getSecureKey() , I exported storeToken

Comment: show `getSecureKey.js` also

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how and where you call your generator function, to be honest.
I would expect a .next() call on your generator function somewhere.

But I hope I am still able to help.
Generator functions will stop at the keyword 'yield'
So your console.log will not be logged (on the first run at least, until you call it again using .next()):

```
function* storeToken() {
  while(true) {
    const keyExists = yield call(getSecureStore()); // execution stops here
    console.log(keyExists); // will not be called during the first 'call'
  }
}
```

I tried to simplify your example:
As you can see the first log does not appear and you are logging the 'previous' key! So your console.log() is off by one. We called the generator function three times, but only logged twice

```js
function foo() {
  
  return true;
}

function* storeToken() {
  while(true) {
    const keyExists = foo();
    yield keyExists
    console.log(keyExists);
  }
}


var generatoreStore = storeToken();
generatoreStore.next(); // nothing logged here -> console.log not reached
generatoreStore.next(); // log appears: exists: true
generatoreStore.next(); // 2nd log appears: exists: true
```

so you might want to use it like this by calling .value on your generator which returns the value at the 'yield' keyword:

```js
function foo() {
  
  return true;
}

function* storeToken() {
  while(true) {
    yield foo();
  }
}

var generatoreStore = storeToken();
console.log(generatoreStore.next().value) // log: true
console.log(generatoreStore.next().value) // log: true
```

another solution might be to 'yield' after the console.log() if you need to use it inside that method

```
function* storeToken() {
  while(true) {
     const keyExists = foo();
     console.log(keyExists);
     yield;
  }
}
```

Comment: @localdata01 any feedback on this?